# Struts 2 grid no getting displayed

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, struts2

Hi I am working with struts 2 jQuery grid plugin. But Its not working. I tried almost everything. But grid is not getting displayed. Here is my code

```jsp
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsontable" />
<sjg:grid id="gridTable" caption="login ID" dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}" pager="true" gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20" rowNum="15" rownumbers="true">
<sjg:gridColumn name="id" title="ID"></sjg:gridColumn>
<sjg:gridColumn name="name" title="Name"></sjg:gridColumn>
<sjg:gridColumn name="mob" title="mobile"></sjg:gridColumn>
</sjg:grid>
```

**Struts.xml**

```xml
<package name="mypackage" namespace="/" extends="struts-default, json-default">
     <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult" default="true"/>
            <result-type name="dispatcher" class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult" default="true"/>
        </result-types>
<action name="mis" class="com.action.JsonAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/mis.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/mis.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="jsontable" class="com.action.JsonAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsp/mis.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

**Action CLass**

```
public class JsonAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List<CustomerModel> gridModel;
    private int rows = 0;
    private int page = 0;
    private String sortAsc;
    private String sortIndex;
    private String searchField;
    private String searchOprtn;
    private int total = 0;
    private int records = 0;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        int to = (rows * page);
        int from = to - rows;
        JsonActionDao jsn = new JsonActionDaoImpl();
        records = jsn.getNoOfRecords();
        gridModel = jsn.getRecords();
        total = (int) Math.ceil((double) records / (double) rows);
        System.out.println("row "+rows+"page "+page+"gridModel "+gridModel);
        return "success";
      // getter and setter for fields.,,,....
    }
}
```

**CustomerModel**

```
package com.model;

public class CustomerModel {

    int id;
    String name;
    int mob;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getMob() {
        return mob;
    }
    public void setMob(int mob) {
        this.mob = mob;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerModel [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", mob=" + mob + "]";
    }

}
```

I think my action class is not returning a object of type json. Do i need to do something for that. Might be there is something that I am missing out since I am new to the stuffs like json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by including struts jq tag

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-jquery-tags" prefix="sj" %>
```

and following line

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
```